# How to Override in magento 2.4.4 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Address.php

Tags: magento2.4

Hi I am facing issue deprecating issue of below explode function,

```
public function getStreet()
    {
        if (is_array($this->getData(OrderAddressInterface::STREET))) {
            return $this->getData(OrderAddressInterface::STREET);
        }
        return explode(PHP_EOL, $this->getData(OrderAddressInterface::STREET));
    }
```

And for this i want to override this file and following below steps,
di.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order" type="Vendor\Coreextended\Model\Order" />
</config>
```

file path Vendor/Coreextended/Model/Order/Address.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Coreextended\Model\Order;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AddressModelInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\AbstractModel;
class Address extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order implements OrderAddressInterface, AddressModelInterface
{
    

    /**
     * Retrieve street field of an address
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getStreet()
    {
        if (is_array($this->getData(OrderAddressInterface::STREET))) {
            return $this->getData(OrderAddressInterface::STREET);
        }
        return explode(PHP_EOL, $this->getData(OrderAddressInterface::STREET) ?? '');
    }

    
}
```

but getting error

> [message] => Class "Vendor\Coreextended\Model\Order" does not exist
> [code] => -1
> [trace] => #0 /home/theboozybutton/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(34):
> ReflectionClass->__construct()
> #1 /home/theboozybutton/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(54):
> Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor()
> #2 /home/theboozybutton/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(100):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters()
> #3 /home/theboozybutton/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is an error in your **di.xml** file. The preference for should be `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address`, not Magento\Sales\Model\Order and type should be `Vendor\Coreextended\Model\Order\Address`, not Vendor\Coreextended\Model\Order.

Also, in your custom Address class **Vendor\Coreextended\Model\Order\Address**, you are extending \Magento\Sales\Model\Order which is not correct, it should be extend from **\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address**

Here is how the corrected **di.xml** file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address" type="Vendor\Coreextended\Model\Order\Address"/>
</config>
```

And the corrected custom class should look like:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Coreextended\Model\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface;

class Address extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address
{
    public function getStreet()
    {
        if (is_array($this->getData(OrderAddressInterface::STREET))) {
            return $this->getData(OrderAddressInterface::STREET);
        }
        return explode(PHP_EOL, $this->getData(OrderAddressInterface::STREET) ?? '');
    }
}
```

Clear the cache by running the command:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

and re-run the code, and it should work without any issues.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks working fine